# Sitecore rendering contents resolver - need content from both context item and datasource item

Tags: jss

We are working on `Sitecore 10.3 Headless`.

For one of the components we are developing, we need the title field from the `context item` and rest of the content from `Datasource item`.

[image]

In this case if we select `Context Item Resolver` then we miss content from Datasource item and if we select `Datasource Resolver` then we miss content from context item.

Do we need to create a `Custom Item resolver` which has content from context item and also from Datasource item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom content rendering resolver is one option. But also, if you are using Next.js you can always use the `useSitecoreContext` hook and access the context item fields from that object. This will save you writing custom code.

For an example you can look at the Headless SXA `Page Content` component. This will use a datasource item if provided, otherwise it will use the context item:

```
const { sitecoreContext } = useSitecoreContext();

const field = (props.fields && props.fields.Content
  ? props.fields.Content
  : sitecoreContext?.route?.fields?.Content) as RichTextField;
```

Ref: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/7d2b47bf9495b4301ecc07f5f62f852fb2e34f87/packages/create-sitecore-jss/src/templates/nextjs-sxa/src/components/PageContent.tsx#L35C21-L35C21

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create Custom Contents Resolver.

You can access Datasource and also Context Item without any problem in Custom Contents Resolver.

Just create custom resolver with Use Context Item checkbox checked:

[image]

Then in Custom Contents Resolver code, you can access both:

- item - will give you access to Context Item
- rendering - will give you access to datasource

[image]